# How to make AngularJS to update view automatically if property was changed?

Tags: angularjs

I try to use AngularJS framework to make automatic update of model-view. I have html file, where I use controller and get values from it (like {{controllerName.values[0].value}}).
app.js is next:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('ModuleName', []);

app.controller('ControllerName', function(){
    this.values = storeValues;

});

function move() {
    storeValues[0].value = 2;
};

var storeValues = [
{
    value: 1
},
...
];
```

When the value in storeValues array is changed in move function, the view on html is not chaning.
What is the right way to use model-view system to change value in view using move function?

**Update:** 
I've not yet understood the reason, but the call of $scope.$apply(); at the end of move() function solved my issue.

Comment: I would highly read up and do a few tutorials on how to use angular. This is some basic angular stuff, and it doesn't look like you know how to use it just yet. They have a great starter tutorial at angularjs.org that should help clarify.

Comment: Calling $apply will force a digest cycle and redraw some part of the DOM. Maybe you'r calling move from somewhere that is not manage by angular. As @MathewBerg said you should read some tutorial first, it will help understand how angular manage the DOM ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a property, you need to attach it to the $scope. 
Try this:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('ModuleName', []);

app.controller('ControllerName', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.values = storeValues;

});

function move() {
    storeValues[0].value = 2;
};

var storeValues = [
{
    value: 1
},
...
]);
```

Comment: I don't believe you have to do this anymore, doing a this in a controller automatically does it. (Depending on your angular version).